# Using adhesive to fit FM1 cooler bracket in non standard HP motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, cooling, computer-building

First of all, I know this is not ideal but here's the situation.. Having built multiple systems myself, I bought a load of components second hand to teach someone else how to build a PC from scratch. I made the mistake of buying a HP FM1 socket motherboard which obviously (because it's HP) does not use the standard FM1 brackets for mounting a cooler.

I have tried to find a cooler which originally fit on this motherboard but I can't find any.. So I'm left with a pretty much useless motherboard.

I have brackets which would fit a standard FM1 motherboard.. my idea is now to use Tiger seal (a sealant / adhesive often used to secure things onto the exterior of cars, so it's meant to be very strong) to glue these brackets to the motherboard so that I can install the CPU cooler.

If I somehow break the motherboard during the process it's not really a big deal because it's useless without being able to install a CPU cooler anyway. What I'm interested to know, is does anyone have a better idea of how to secure this without being able to use the normal backplate and bracket screwed onto the motherboard?

[image: FM1 socket]

**Update, my horrific solution:**
[image: Solution]

Comment: You are best to fabricate your own brackets that use the factory holes in the motherboard.

Comment: Random unknown high-strength adhesives and electronics do not mix. The high-strength adhesive may have chemicals that react with the PCB fibreglass content, coverlay and/or copper and otherwise cause damage. Even if it is not corrosive if it bonds completely enough the weight of a large chunk of metal cooler (and the tens of lbs of force required to keep the cooler pressed firmly enough against the CPU) to actually do the job may mean the adhesive literally rips the tracks or components up from the PCB. Buy the right cooler. Even if you have to go to eBay.

Comment: @Moab I wouldn't know where to start with that :(

Comment: @Mokubai I've already tried eBay and I can't find any new or used for any sort of sensible price (I found 1 used for £75). I'm thinking I may as well try the adhesive because worst case is that the motherboard breaks, but it's useless without a bracket anyway?

Comment: @EM-Creations I looked also, didn't find any, if you had the original HP part number you have a better chance finding one.

Comment: As it is a HP custom board then the best course is probably to fight your way through their support lines to find out if/where you can get a replacement cooler. Adhesives for essentially welding things to your car are going to be a lot more "lively" than ones you would typically want near delicate electronics. If you are happy with the likelihood of turning a potential paperweight into an *actual* paperweight while at the same time throwing away whatever CPU, heatsink and adhesive you manage to cobble together then that's your shout. As it stands people can only guess at what might happen.

Comment: I have edited the question with my horror show of a solution. I'm willing to give it a try as a learning exercise.

Comment: This didn't work btw... mounts came loose after a few days. I got a new motherboard in the end.